# Ford Figo not starting immobilizer

Tags: electrical, electronic-control-module, computer, immobilizer

I have a ford figo 2012 petrol automatic that is not starting. When I turn the ignition to “ON”, all the lights on the dashboard come on and the immobilizer light blinks. The car used to start before. In scanned the car and the codes came up as shown in the images. Anyone know what could be the problem?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing to do with this is get your battery checked. Then if bad, replace it. Then when you have a working battery, check the charging system. Make sure all battery and charging system cables are cleaned and not defective. This can not be diagnosed until these steps are taken and done properly. It may even solve the problems.

Answer (score -1):

When the mobilizer lock come on blinking i normally warm up the and i have come to realize that when ever the key is cold the car fails to start try it and get back to us and see if it helps simply put your key some where warm or in your hands and breath in it some warm breath it helps me